# DateTime parse string containing day of year

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I'm trying to parse a string formatted like so:

```
1900-001T00:00:00Z
```

into a DateTime object. The middle bit there (right after the "1900-" and before the "T") is supposed to be the day of year. I know the rest of the formatting string I would need to use would be

```
yyyy-XXXTHH:mm:ssZ
```

but what should I put in for that 'XXX'?

Comment: As far as I know `DateTime` formatters do not support day of year, so you'll have to roll your own code to do that.

Comment: extract it, replace it with 01-01 then add that number of days after the parse?

Comment: so you mean that if val of XXX is 365 then it means 1 year?

Comment: @Agent_Orange: The values should only be in the range 001 - 364 (for non leap years) where 001 is Jan 1 and 364 is Dec 31

Comment: @Agent_Orange 365 would December 31 on most years and the 30th on leap years anything over 366 would not be valid.

Comment: @redsoxfantom There are 365 days in most years and 366 in a leap year.  The only way 364 is Dec 31st is if Jan 1st is 0.

Comment: @AlexK. You'd add the parsed number minus one so that if it is 001 you add 0 days to January 1st.

Comment: If you do need to write your own, `TimeSpan.FromDays` is going to be your best friend. Also, *strongly* recommend using `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime`. Search MSDN for articles explaining why, but the short version is that `DateTimeOffset` avoids many nasty timezone problems baked into `DateTime` (and not fixed to avoid breaking 20 years of legacy code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A self written parser could look like this:

```
static DateTime ToDt(string date)
{
    var splitYear = date.Split(new[] { '-' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var splitDays = splitYear[1].Split(new[] { 'T' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var hms = splitDays[1].TrimEnd('Z').Split(':');

    var dt = new DateTime(int.Parse(splitYear[0]), 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    dt = dt.AddDays(int.Parse(splitDays[0]) - 1);
    dt = dt.AddHours(int.Parse(hms[0]));
    dt = dt.AddMinutes(int.Parse(hms[1]));
    dt = dt.AddSeconds(int.Parse(hms[2]));

    return dt;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ToDt("1900-001T00:10:00Z"));
    Console.WriteLine(ToDt("1923-180T12:11:10Z"));
    Console.WriteLine(ToDt("1979-365T23:59:59Z"));
    Console.WriteLine(ToDt("2017-074T18:47:10Z"));


    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Output:

```
01.01.1900 00:10:00
29.06.1923 12:11:10
31.12.1979 23:59:59
15.03.2017 18:47:10
```

This will throw if

- splits are not returning the expected amount of splits (ill formatting) **`IndexOutOfRangeException`**
- numbers are not parsable to int **`FormatException`**

and int won't guard against "nonsensical but wellformed" inputs

```
'2000-999T99:99:99Z'   -->  29.09.2002 04:40:39
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there's a fancier way, but you could write your own method to do it:

```
private static DateTime CustomParseDayOfYear(string input)
{
    if (input == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(input));

    var parts = input.Split('-', 'T');
    if (parts.Length != 3) throw new FormatException(nameof(input));

    var timeParts = parts[2].Trim('Z').Split(':');
    if (timeParts.Length != 3) throw new FormatException(nameof(input));

    int hour, minute, second, year, dayOfYear;

    if (!int.TryParse(parts[0], out year))
        throw new FormatException("Year must be an integer");
    if (!int.TryParse(parts[1], out dayOfYear))
        throw new FormatException("DayOfYear must be an integer");
    if (!int.TryParse(timeParts[0], out hour))
        throw new FormatException("Hour must be an integer");
    if (!int.TryParse(timeParts[1], out minute))
        throw new FormatException("Minute must be an integer");
    if (!int.TryParse(timeParts[2], out second))
        throw new FormatException("Second must be an integer");

    var maxDayOfYear = new DateTime(year, 12, 31).DayOfYear;

    if (year < 1 || year > 9999)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
            "Year must be greater than zero and less than 10000");
    if (dayOfYear < 1 || dayOfYear > maxDayOfYear)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
            $"DayOfYear must be greater than zero and less than {maxDayOfYear + 1}");
    if (hour > 23) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"Hour must be less than 24");
    if (minute > 59) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"Minute must less than 60");
    if (second > 59) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"Second must less than 60");

    return new DateTime(year, 1, 1, hour, minute, second).AddDays(dayOfYear - 1);
}
```

Comment: What happes if you feed it `'2000-999T99:99:99Z'`? Explicit exception throwing is nicer then my "let them fly" approach +1

Comment: Added some check for year/dayofyear/hour/minute/second values. Thanks @PatrickArtner!

Comment: You've been a bit over-exuberant with that extra check `year < 1 || year > 999`! You could avoid all this extra checking by avoiding reinventing the wheel. for example my answer uses DateTime.ParseExact, which may be why it's the simplest so far.

Comment: @Richardissimo Yeah, I just added these as examples where you could give specific exceptions about why the parse failed (which I didn't - I guess I can add that for completeness). But you're right, I could just let it fail on the last line since `DateTime` will already throw if any of those conditions are true.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @AlexK's suggestion, here you go, nice and simple...

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

    private DateTime? ParseDayOfYearDate(string value)
    {
        DateTime? result = null;
        Regex dayOfYearDatePattern = new Regex(@"^(\d+\-)(\d+)(.+)$");
        Match dayOfYearDateMatch = dayOfYearDatePattern.Match(value);
        if (dayOfYearDateMatch.Success)
        {
            string altered = dayOfYearDateMatch.Groups[1].Value + "01-01" + dayOfYearDateMatch.Groups[3].Value;
            int dayOfYear = int.Parse(dayOfYearDateMatch.Groups[2].Value); // will succeed due to the definition of the pattern
            DateTime startOfYear = DateTime.ParseExact(altered, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssK", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);
            result = startOfYear.AddDays(dayOfYear - 1); // since we already gave it 1st January
        }
        else
        {
            // It didn't match the pattern, will return null.
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Point to note: if you included the fractions of a second in that string before the Z, this approach would be able to pass the ISO standard "O" as the parameter for the format, instead of the "yyyy-MM-dd..." nastiness.